# Python Facebook SDK get my own photos

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to write a python script with [Facebook SDK for Python](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to download all my own photos.

```
 my_token = 'user_access_token'
 import facebook
 graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=my_token, version='2.7')
 photos = graph.get_connections(id='me', connection_name='photos')
 photos
```

But photo is an empty dict.

```
{'data': []}
```

I realized I only had user_friends, public_profile permission per my user access token which is generated with my own fb account and if i need more than those permission I need to apply for an app review ["Apps that ask for more than public_profile, email and user_friends must be reviewed by Facebook before they can be made available to the general public."](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/permissions)

Do I really need to apply for a review for my so called app, which is just a python script in order to download my own photos or am I missing something here

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: Thanks; this is much more to the point than the initial posting.  It moves past the point of my answer, which I'm deleting.

Comment: @CBroe I'm listed as an administrator on my app so i should have full access right?

Comment: and I'm using a user_token generated for my my test app

Comment: And does that token include user_photos permission, or not? Debug it to verify.

Comment: @CBroe, i realized user_token only has public_profile, user_friends permissions, and stumbled on Graph API explorer page which lets me get a  token with specific permission,it makes me wonder why such thing is available in the App settings or under access token tool...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a developer account using my facebook account. I created a test app and i am the administrator of the app. I am using my user_token which i thought as an administrator, i have access to all kinds of permission but it doesn't have photo_permission, only public_profile and user_friends.

```
permission = graph.get_permissions(user_id = user_id)
permission
{'public_profile', 'user_friends'}
```

It took me some detour to figure out how to get permission to user_photo without app review, as someone suggested earlier it may involved logging in as myself, that didn't take me anywhere. Then I stumbled on [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) which lets me generate an access token with whatever permissions you need. you just need to check the boxes! [image]
Now when I use this new token to get photo permission

```
permission = graph.get_permissions(user_id = user_id)
permission
{'public_profile', 'user_friends', 'user_photos'}
```

And photos is not an empty dict anymore

```
len(photos['data'])
25
```